# what the difference between following situation in iOS?

Tags: ios, properties

i think there are two ways to add a UIControl in my view

status 1:

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) UIButton *button;

- (void)viewDidload
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button........ (set frame,color,text........)
    [self.view addSubView:button];
    _button = button;
}
```

status 2.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIButton *button;

- (void)viewDidload
{
    _button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    _button.......(set frame,color,text......)
    [self.view addSubView:_button];
}
```

i want to know the difference between them and in different situation what should i chose ?

Comment: You want to ask the `weak` and `strong` difference, or the 'Direct' setting `button` and  then `_button`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in version 1 (**nonatomic, strong**) the viewcontroller keeps a strong reference to the button. that means if you for example remove it from the superview somewhere in your code (`[self.button removeFromSuperview];`) it is still in memory and could be readded at a later point in time (`[self.view addSubview:self.button];`).

in version 2 (**nonatomic, weak**) the viewcontroller keeps a weak reference to the button. that means if you for example remove it from the superview somewhere in your code (and no other part of your app keeps a strong reference to it) it gets deallocated.

there is no real difference between creating a local variable `UIButton *button = ...` and assigning it to the instance variable afterwards `_button = button;` or working with the instance variable directly `_button = [UIButton buttonWithType:...`.

Comment: There is a lot more in the scenarios. Ownership is just one point in this.
Read up on properties, setters-getters, scope. "there is no real difference..." this statement is downright incorrect.

Comment: in this button scenario there aren't any setters involved at all. that is why i wrote "no real difference"... it's just that he uses a "temporary local variable" in the one but not in the other case - nevertheless it would be helpful to read some more about properties and stuff - sure.

Answer (score 0):

in status 1:

you have marked you UIButton as weak Property
and A weak reference means the pointer has no owner, therefore it will be deallocated as soon as it is no longer needed (that is, nothing else is pointing to it).

but in status 2 :

you have marked you UIButton as Strong Property and when your Button hasn't mark as IBOutlet , you should use strong